# How to access # separated parameters from url in java

Tags: java, url, servlets

```
https://apps.facebook.com/atri-apps/next.jsp#access_token=AAADDZAgrM9vcBAA
```

I want to access the `access_token` parameter from url but I am not able to do it.
I am using `.getQueryString .getParameterValue()` methods of request object of a servlet. But they are not working as their is no '?' sign after `next.jsp`.

Can any one can help me to get `access_token` parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#` denotes a URL anchor, not a query parameter, and they are not added to the query string. As a result, they don't get sent to the server, they stay only on the client. Your servlet has no way of accessing them.

If you need the server to read them, you need to use a query string parameter, e.g.

```
https://apps.facebook.com/atri-apps/next.jsp?access_token=AAADDZAgrM9vcBAA
```

Note the `?` instead of the `#`

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @skaffman said above, you can access the anchor information through the client-side JavaScript:

```
     var hash = location.hash;
```

The way you could use it is through a sort of an asynchronous communication with your server (see AJAX).